# Unexpected Results from jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am using jquery/ajax to modify an html form before it is submitted. I was having issues with my code so I added in a few alert lines to help me debug. When my code does not contain the alert lines, it does not work. When my code contains the alert lines, it does work. I cannot fathom any reason for the alert boxes effecting the functionality of my code so if someone can tell me when I am missing that would be awesome. I am hoping it is something simple I am overlooking. Code snippits below.

DOES WORK:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#clientName").autocomplete({source: '../Controller/clientAutoComplete.php', minLength:3});   
            });
            function update(){
                alert("in update");
                $.get('../Controller/clientidGrab.php', {term: $("#clientName").val()}, function(data){
                    alert("in get");
                    alert($("#clientName").val());
                    var changed = data[0].id;
                    $("#clientID").val(changed);
                }
                , "json");
            }


    </script>
```

DOES NOT WORK:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#clientName").autocomplete({source: '../Controller/clientAutoComplete.php', minLength:3});   
            });
            function update(){
                $.get('../Controller/clientidGrab.php', {term: $("#clientName").val()}, function(data){
                    var changed = data[0].id;
                    $("#clientID").val(changed);
                }
                , "json");
            }


    </script>
```

EDIT

I have narrowed it down even further. The page runs properly if the line: `alert("In update");` is included. The other 2 alert lines do not seems to matter.

Comment: When the code is working, the #client ID field is populated with the proper client ID. When the code is not working, the client ID field is first populated with 507 (incorrect) and then stops updating all together.

Comment: How do you call update() method? Any error in console?

Comment: If the update method is called, please provide the code that execute it. Besides end points differs. It seems that your data come from the endpoint mentioned in update. Are you aware of it?

Comment: Here is the part of my code that calls up the update() function. `<tr><td>Client Matter Number:</td><td> <input type="text" id="clientName" name="clientName" onchange="update();"></td></tr>`

Comment: Is it possible the autocomplete script works asynchronously, so that when you alert() something it has enough time to request info but not when running right ahead?

Comment: Possibly, I am not sure though. I have another page with a nearly identical set up that works without the alert boxes. Just a different form. I will wait to see if anyone knows more about the  possible asynchronous timing issue.

Answer (score 0):

remove the onchange from the input.
Add inside the `$(document).ready` this code:

```
$('#clientName').on('change', function(){
    update();
});
```

Comment: That works as well, but still only if the alert statements are included. Without the alert statements it does not work.